# How can I configure multiple <virtualhost> with the same SSL Certificate - Apache

Tags: apache, ssl

Context:

I have a domain: `example.com`, but I would like to create a domain like `api.example.com` to use it like a web-service.

The last night, I've got a free SSL Certificate using *Let's Encrypt*.

My domain `example.com` should open the content in `/var/www/website/`.

My domain `api.example.com` should open the content in `/var/www/api/`.

I've looking for some information on the Internet, and I've created these files in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`

#### /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName  example.com
    DocumentRoot    /var/www/website/

    LogLevel debug
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com/error.log

        <Directory "/var/www/website/">
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName  example.com
    DocumentRoot    /var/www/website/

    LogLevel debug
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com/error_ssl.log

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateFile      /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com/chain.pem

        <Directory "/var/www/website/">
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

#### /etc/apache2/sites-available/api.example.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName  api.example.com
    DocumentRoot    /var/www/api/

    #RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]

        <Directory "/var/www/api/">
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName  api.example.com
    DocumentRoot    /var/www/api/

    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateFile      /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com/chain.pem

        <Directory "/var/www/api/">
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I've created two files because I though we need to separate the domains, but when I try to enter to `example.com` I've got the content in `api.example.com`.

With *Let's encrypt*, I've created the same SSL Certificate for both domains and the file are in `/etc/apache2/ssl/example.com/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution!

I've edited the `httpd.conf` and the `ports.conf`.

#### /etc/apache2/ports.conf

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
# This is also true if you have upgraded from before 2.2.9-3 (i.e. from
# Debian etch). See /usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/NEWS.Debian.gz and
# README.Debian.gz

NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80

NameVirtualHost *:443

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
    # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
    # to <VirtualHost *:443>
    # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
    # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

#### /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

```
SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck on
```

Now I could use the domain for the website and the webservice